# Firebase signIn issue in React Native Expo production build - Crashes after selecting Google account in SigninScreen

Tags: react-native, firebase-authentication, expo, google-signin, react-native-firebase

## Firebase signIn issue in React Native Expo production build - Crashes after selecting Google account in SigninScreen

I am facing a critical issue in my **React Native app where the app crashes abruptly after selecting a Google account during the signin process, but only in the production build.** In the development build (Expo), the app works fine without any crashes. The next time the app opens the checkedSignIn function works fine which means sign in was successful but the doc is not created in the firestore.

Overview:

- The issue occurs specifically in the production build of my React Native app.
- The crash happens after selecting a Google account during the signin process.
- The expected behavior is to complete the signin process and setUser() to the logged in user.
- The app works fine in the development build (Expo) without any crashes or issues.

**Edit [ after further logging it looks like the code stops at this line as no further logs are shown after this and app crashes: ]**

```
 const { user } = await auth().signInWithCredential(googleCredential);
```

Relevant Code:
Here is the relevant code snippet from my useAuth hook:

```
// ...

const signInWithGoogle = async () => {
  try {
    setLoading(true);
    await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices({ showPlayServicesUpdateDialog: true });
    const { idToken } = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
    const googleCredential = auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken);
    const { user } = await auth().signInWithCredential(googleCredential);
    await setUserInFirestore(user);
    

  } catch (error) {
    setError(error);
    console.log("Error signing in with Google:", error);
  }
};

// ...
```

```
const setUserInFirestore = async (user) => {
    const { uid, displayName, email, photoURL } = user;

    try {
      const userRef = doc(db, "users", uid);
      const snapshot = await getDoc(userRef);

      if (!snapshot.exists()) {
        await setDoc(userRef, {
          displayName,
          email,
          photoURL,
          uid,
          subscription: null,
        });
      }

      setUser(user);
      setUserContext(user);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error adding user to Firestore:", error.message);
      navigation.navigate(routes.WELCOME);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };
```

Versions:

- React Native: 0.71.8
- Expo: ~48.0.15
- @react-native-firebase/app: ^17.4.3
- @react-native-firebase/auth: ^17.4.3
- @react-native-google-signin/google-signin: ^9.0.2
- Firebase: ^9.21.0
- 

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Crash in React Native app when authorizing via @react-native-google-signin/google-signin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76875452/crash-in-react-native-app-when-authorizing-via-react-native-google-signin-googl)

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was that I needed to **open Xcode** and:

1. Go to my **GoogleService-Info.plist** file
2. Copy the value of the `REVERSED_CLIENT_ID`
3. Navigate to the project's TARGETS and select my app
4. Select the **Info** tab and navigate to the **URL Types** section
5. Add a new item to the URL Types section by tapping on the plus (+) icon
6. Paste the value of the `REVERSED_CLIENT_ID` in the URL Schemes field.

In case you feel these instructions are not clear enough, you can [watch this video](https://youtu.be/TdyiHng-1Ks?si=Gfg8CwrnXkuVS-Rg&t=320) that goes through these steps at **5:20**

Comment: Finally something that works! These instructions are not in the [getting started steps](https://rnfirebase.io/) of the RNfirebase.io documentation so thank you for highlighting this extra step!