# Crash in React Native app when authorizing via @react-native-google-signin/google-signin

Tags: react-native, google-signin

I have a problem with google-authorization via @react-native-google-signin/google-signin library. In android authorization works correctly, in ios it crashes. Fragment of the crash log:

```
...
AppStoreTools:       14E221
AppVariant:          1:iPhone11,8:16
Beta:                YES
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2023-08-10 13:38:04.8666 +0300
Launch Time:         2023-08-10 13:38:02.2774 +0300
OS Version:          iPhone OS 16.5.1 (20F770750d)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    5.02.02
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  1

...

Thread 1 name:
Thread 1 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000020d9b6558 __pthread_kill + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022e7f7118 pthread_kill + 268 (pthread.c:1670)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001d5f9b178 abort + 180 (abort.c:118)
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000022e735bf8 abort_message + 132 (:-1)
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000022e725444 demangling_terminate_handler() + 348 (:-1)
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001c7b21ea4 _objc_terminate() + 144 (objc-exception.mm:498)
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000022e734fbc std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16 (:-1)
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000022e734f60 std::terminate() + 56 (:-1)
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001d5f3aec0 _dispatch_client_callout + 40 (object.m:563)
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001d5f42534 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 668 (queue.c:3885)
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001d5f430a4 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 384 (queue.c:3976)
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001d5f4dcdc _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 648 (queue.c:6507)
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022e7f0ddc _pthread_wqthread + 288 (pthread.c:2618)
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022e7f0b7c start_wqthread + 8 (:-1)

...

Thread 1 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x000000022e739647   x5: 0x000000016b6d2850   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0x0000000000000300
    x8: 0x1999e4bb343495b2   x9: 0x1999e4ba5f59a5b2  x10: 0x0000000000000200  x11: 0x000000000000000b
   x12: 0x000000000000000b  x13: 0x00000000001ff800  x14: 0x00000000000007fb  x15: 0x0000000095634010
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x000000016b6d3000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x0000000000001c03  x21: 0x000000016b6d30e0  x22: 0x0000000000000000  x23: 0x000000016b6d30e0
   x24: 0x0000000280841068  x25: 0x0000000000000000  x26: 0x0000000000000114  x27: 0x000000028334d940
   x28: 0x000000028334d940   fp: 0x000000016b6d27c0   lr: 0x000000022e7f7118
    sp: 0x000000016b6d27a0   pc: 0x000000020d9b6558 cpsr: 0x40000000
   esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault

...
```

My code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { GoogleSignin } from '@react-native-google-signin/google-signin';

export default function Start() {

  const signIn = async () => {
    try {
      await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices();
      const item: any = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
      console.log('tokens', item);
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.log('error', error);
    }
  };

  const isSignedIn = async () => {
    const isSignedIn1 = await GoogleSignin.isSignedIn();
    if (!!isSignedIn1) {
      getCurrentUserInfo();
    } else {
      console.log('Login Please');
    }
  };

  const getCurrentUserInfo = async () => {
    try {
      const userInfo1 = await GoogleSignin.signInSilently();
      console.log(userInfo1);
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.log('Error', error.message);
    }
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    GoogleSignin.configure({
      scopes: [
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
      ],
      webClientId:
        '...',
      offlineAccess: true,
      forceCodeForRefreshToken: true,
    });
    isSignedIn();
  }, []);

  return (
      <View>
        <React.Button
          onPress={() => signIn()}
          title="Grant account access"
        />
      </View>
  );
}
```

The crash happens on the lines

```
await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices();
const item: any = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
```

(when calling the signIn function, before displaying information to the console).

Help to understand what could be the problem on iOS. How to fix it?

I followed all steps for IOS installation https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-google-signin/blob/master/ios-guide.md
I checked that the GoogleSignIn module was installed correctly in cocoapods.
Reinstalled @react-native-google-signin/google-signin module
The crash happens both in the emulator and in TestFlight.

My dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^10.0.1",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.8",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.13",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "@types/react-navigation": "^3.4.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.3",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.1"
  },
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase signIn issue in React Native Expo production build - Crashes after selecting Google account in SigninScreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76322313/firebase-signin-issue-in-react-native-expo-production-build-crashes-after-sele)

Comment: @NikitasIO I'm dup-voting the other way around. I think this Q is more clear about the relation to the google signin package, and this one has more answers and views (which I think speaks to its searchability).

Answer (score 14):

Personally, my app crashed specifically on **iOS** as well when I would call the **GoogleSignin.signIn()** method.

To resolve the issue, I needed to **open Xcode** and:

1. Go to my **GoogleService-Info.plist** file
2. Copy the value of the `REVERSED_CLIENT_ID`
3. Navigate to the project's TARGETS and select my app
4. Select the **Info** tab and navigate to the **URL Types** section
5. Add a new item to the URL Types section by tapping on the plus (+) icon
6. Paste the value of the `REVERSED_CLIENT_ID` in the URL Schemes field.

In case you feel these instructions are not clear enough, you can [watch this video](https://youtu.be/TdyiHng-1Ks?si=Gfg8CwrnXkuVS-Rg&t=320) that goes through these steps at **5:20**

Comment: This solution worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: This really worked thanks

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading react-native-google-signin/google-signin to 9.0.2 will fix this issue.

Comment: After installing version 9.0.2, the crash remained: 

...
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 6 Abort trap: 6

Comment: My react native version was 0.71.10.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is similar to what Nikitas IO mentioned.

I was crashing immediately on:

```
const userInfo = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
```

The stack trace gave me a clue:

> 3   REDACTED_APP_NAME                0x10a45f415 -[GIDSignIn signInWithOptions:] + 501 (GIDSignIn.m:517)
> 4   REDACTED_APP_NAME                0x10a45e1d0 -[GIDSignIn signInWithPresentingViewController:hint:additionalScopes:completion:] + 208 (GIDSignIn.m:260)
> 5   REDACTEDAPP_NAME                 0x10a499f07 __43-[RNGoogleSignin signIn:resolver:rejecter:]_block_invoke + 375 (RNGoogleSignin.m:106)

However I wasn't using Firebase so I didn't have a GoogleService-info.plist file. But Nikitas IO answer did set me on the right track, I just needed to add the reversed google clientID to my Info.plist file and it worked.

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
 <dict>
  <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
  <string>Editor</string>
  <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
  <array>
   <string>REVERSED_CLIENT_ID</string>
  </array>
 </dict>
</array>
```